# Parameterize an SQL query in Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to build a `python` script that will run a `COPY` command in a database connection while accepting parameters.

Database: Amazon Redshift, connecting with the `psycopg2` package.
COPY command pulling the data from Amazon S3.

If I hardcode any of the values, the command works fine, but if I add a parameter, the query fails.

#### Parameters:

```
access_key = 'my_amazon_acccess_key'
secret_key = 'my_amazon_secret_key'
bucketname = 'my_amazon_s3_bucket_name'
filename = 'my_gzipped_file.gz'
```

Code I am trying to parameterize:

#### Version 1

```
cur.execute("
    COPY Schema.tablename FROM 's3://%s/%s' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=%s;aws_secret_access_key=%s' NULL 'NULL' gzip delimiter =',';", 
    (bucketname, filename, access_key, secret_key))
```

#### Version 1 error:

```
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "my_amazon_s3_bucket_name"
LINE 2:  COPY Schema.tablename FROM 's3://'my_amazon_s3_bucket_name'/'my_gzipped_file.gz'...
```

#### Version 2

```
cur.execute("
    COPY Schema.tablename FROM 's3://?/?' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=?;aws_secret_access_key=?' NULL 'NULL' gzip delimiter =',';", 
    (bucketname, filename, access_key, secret_key))
```

#### Version 3

```
cur.execute("
    COPY Schema.tablename FROM 's3://$1/$2' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=$3;aws_secret_access_key=$4' NULL 'NULL' gzip delimiter =',';", 
    (bucketname, filename, access_key, secret_key))
```

#### Version 2 & Version 3 error (same message):

```
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<> in <module>()
      1 cur.execute("""
      2         COPY Schema.tablename FROM 's3://?/?' credentials ' aws_acces
s_key_id=?;aws_secret_access_key=?' NULL 'NULL' gzip delimiter ',';""",
----> 3         (bucketname, filename, access_key, secret_key))

InternalError: Invalid credentials. Must be of the format: credentials 'aws_acce
ss_key_id=<access-key-id>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret-access-key>[;token=<temp
orary-session-token>]'
DETAIL:
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid credentials. Must be of the format: credentials 'aws_access_ke
y_id=<access-key-id>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret-access-key>[;token=<temporary
-session-token>]'
  code:      8001
  context:
  query:     95221
  location:  aws_credentials_parser.cpp:86
  process:   padbmaster [pid=326]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

I would prefer not to hard code these parameters, but can't figure out a way to properly handle this.  Can this be done?

Comment: It's worth asking -- what if you pass the entire S3 URL or the credentials string as a single parameter? That is to say, `FROM %s credentials %s`, no quoted strings needed? If that isn't supported (which is possible, depending on the details of how the COPY command is parsed, which I haven't looked up docs for yet), then what I'm suggesting in my answer won't work either. (OTOH, the fixes I've implemented are quite definitely necessary; putting a sigil inside quotes does quote it, after all).

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed the delimiters inside your (SQL) strings; you need to use string concatenation (the SQL string concatenation operator being `||`) **inside the database engine** -- as opposed to what you're doing now, which assumes expansion *before* content is handed off to the database engine to parse.

That is to say, your query string should include:

```
's3://' || %s || '/' || %s
```

...to prefix `s3://`, add a string from parameters, a `/`, another string from parameters, etc. When you put a `%s` inside a SQL string, it's treated as literal, not a placeholder.

---

In context (and using a different, arguably clearer, available quoting form), this might look like:

```
cur.execute("""
    COPY Schema.tablename FROM 's3://' || %(bucketname)s || '/' || %(filename)s
      credentials 'aws_access_key_id=' || %(access_key)s ||
                  ';aws_secret_access_key=' || %(secret_key)s
      NULL 'NULL' gzip delimiter =',';""", 
    {'bucketname': bucketname, 'filename': filename, 'access_key': access_key, 'secret_key': secret_key})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to use `AsIs`:

```
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs

access_key = 'my_amazon_acccess_key'
secret_key = 'my_amazon_secret_key'
bucketname = 'my_amazon_s3_bucket_name'
filename = 'my_gzipped_file.gz'

print cur.mogrify('''
    COPY Schema.tablename
    FROM 's3://%s/%s'
    credentials 'aws_access_key_id=%s;aws_secret_access_key=%s'
    NULL 'NULL' gzip delimiter =','
    ;''', 
    (AsIs(bucketname), AsIs(filename), AsIs(access_key), AsIs(secret_key))
)
```

Output:

```
COPY Schema.tablename
FROM 's3://my_amazon_s3_bucket_name/my_gzipped_file.gz'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=my_amazon_acccess_key;aws_secret_access_key=my_amazon_secret_key'
NULL 'NULL' gzip delimiter =','
;
```

Now the problem is that `COPY` is a server side command. It will be run by the user that runs the server, usually `postgres` which will need to have read permission on the file. Check [`psql` `\copy`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) which runs at the client with the client's permissions or [`psycopg2` `copy_from` or `copy_expert`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from)